# How to find a flag (int) value based on a Hex value in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I need help on something quit confusing but I will try to be very specific. Thanks in advanced.

I have a column in a table (SALES) called FLAG (bigint). 
This value is calculated based on a Hex results which I am not entirely sure. what happen is that depending of the flag number means different outputs as per table below:

[image]

So depending of the value on the FLAG field, it will tell me the meaning and how many meanings that Flag is holding.

My question is, in the database I only have the FLAG number, for example value "8209", how can I find out all records that contain the "Value (Hex) = 2 (Apple). I don't care for anything else as long as I return all FLAGS that have the 2 (Apple) tick?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: TSQL and MySQL, that's a very rare combo.

Comment: they're bit fields. you'd do `select * from yourtable where Value & 8209`. any records with a matching bit would get returned.

Comment: You lost me beetween Int, Hex, Bit. Show us some sample data and desire output

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not too sure how all this bits worked anyway. But I got your query and I will try now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you are describing, it is most-likely a bitfield. These are pretty common in some databases for various (especially historic) reasons.

As you can see, the values are all powers of two:

> 1: Banana
>
> 2: Apple
>
> 4: Investigation
>
> 8: ...

In order to query based on those parameters, you need to use the "bitwise AND" operator (`&` symbol in most languages and SQL dialects).

So, for example, to find all fields where the `FLAG` contains Apple (2), you would structure your where statement like this:

```
... WHERE `FLAG` & 2 = 2
```

This applies to any other value or group of values as well. If it doesn't contain the bitwise value, then `[field] & [value] = 0`, otherwise, it is `[field] & [value] = [value]`.

Let me know if it is still confusing and I can try to explain better!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation. I understood well. I will try and see if I manage to get the results. You are 100% correct on all your explanation. Fantastic. Thank you!